# How can I measure the impact of queries with errors being rejected by SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, performance, sql-server-2014, enterprise-edition, parse

After configuring XE on November 23, 2020 to capture some errors I could count 2,163,665 occurrences of the same error coming from requests of a legacy app (that probably won’t be corrected so soon). The errors can be classified on the 1st and 2nd steps for [Processing a SQL Statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/reference/processing-a-sql-statement?view=sql-server-ver15):

> 1. The DBMS first parses the SQL statement. It breaks the statement up
>    into individual words, called tokens, makes sure that the statement
>    has a valid verb and valid clauses, and so on. Syntax errors and
>    misspellings can be detected in this step.
> 2. The DBMS validates the statement. It checks the statement against
>    the system catalog. Do all the tables named in the statement exist
>    in the database? Do all of the columns exist and are the column
>    names unambiguous? Does the user have the required privileges to
>    execute the statement? Certain semantic errors can be detected in
>    this step.

The doc also says that **Parsing a SQL statement does not require access to the database and can be done very quickly**, but the amount of requests being fired at the server made me think I should verify.

I’d like to measure the resource consumption impact caused by those wrong requests being rejected on those steps. Is there a way to do so?

Comment: How many are "TONS"? I think you will need thousands of these errors per second to have a significant resource impact. You could capture rpc and sql_batch completed events filtered by result = Error and additional filters for the problem app to capture CPU.

Comment: if an event errors does it actually complete ? I don't know but I am doubtful.
Is it right that some of this application works correctly but a few things don't ? 
Maybe what you need is a no-op plan guide - but I think that is a change request :-)

Comment: @DanGuzman, I'd say it's not even close to thousands of errors per sec because it's a small environment, I said tons because of the frequency that was flooding the XE capture  making it really difficult for me to find anything useful until I filtered out those errors. About your suggestion, I'm not sure I follow your idea. Where do I use that filter?

Comment: @StephenMorris-Mo64 I'd guess it always complete because it returns the error message and that's one (undesired) way of completing. "Is it right that some of this application works correctly but a few things don't ?" Yes, the application still works, but this specific request causing the error is continually being sent to the server (and I have no idea of what's broken on the app).

Comment: @DanGuzman I just verified and the XE was configured on my server on 2020-11-23 and it captured 2,163,665 events of the error I mentioned. I know SQL Server can handle that easily (it's been doing it with no problem long before I noticed the errors with XE), but it's good to know what's going on on the server and have a baseline of its load.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see from your comment that the errors are not happening so frequently as to be a performance concern.

To answer the question asked, you could create a filtered XE trace to capture detail sql_batch_completed and rpc_completed events where result is Error. The events can then be summarized by a time interval for aggregated stats.

The example below summarizes the CPU and logical reads by one minute interval from a trace file target.

```
--example trace
CREATE EVENT SESSION [errors] ON SERVER 
ADD EVENT sqlserver.rpc_completed(SET collect_statement=(1)
    WHERE ([result]=(1))),
ADD EVENT sqlserver.sql_batch_completed(
    WHERE ([result]=(1)))
ADD TARGET package0.event_file(SET filename=N'C:\TraceFiles\errors',max_rollover_files=(2))
WITH (MAX_MEMORY=4096 KB,EVENT_RETENTION_MODE=ALLOW_SINGLE_EVENT_LOSS,MAX_DISPATCH_LATENCY=30 SECONDS,MAX_EVENT_SIZE=0 KB,MEMORY_PARTITION_MODE=NONE,TRACK_CAUSALITY=OFF,STARTUP_STATE=OFF);
GO

--example aggregation query
WITH
    event_data AS (
        SELECT CAST(event_data AS XML) AS event_data_xml
        FROM fn_xe_file_target_read_file('C:\TraceFiles\errors*.xel',NULL,NULL,NULL)
    )
    , event_data_fields AS (
        SELECT 
              DATEADD(minute,DATEDIFF(minute,'',event_data_xml.value('(/event/@timestamp)[1]', 'datetime2')),'') AS interval
            , event_data_xml.value('(/event/data[@name="duration"]/value)[1]', 'bigint') AS duration
            , event_data_xml.value('(/event/data[@name="cpu_time"]/value)[1]', 'bigint') AS cpu_time
            , event_data_xml.value('(/event/data[@name="logical_reads"]/value)[1]', 'bigint') AS logical_reads
        FROM event_data
    )
SELECT
      interval
    , SUM(duration) AS duration
    , SUM(cpu_time) AS cpu_time
    , SUM(logical_reads) AS logical_reads
FROM event_data_fields
GROUP BY interval
ORDER BY interval;
```

Comment: Dan Guzman, thanks a lot! I've been using the `EVENT sqlserver.error_reported` and I'm not sure it has a value for `cpu_time` (still learning XE). I just tested your code on my desktop and it seems to be exactly what I was looking for. Also, I see this will be useful to count the total of correct requests my server receives if I change the `result = (1)` to `result = (0)` according to the possible values for the Error column for the [RPC:Completed Event Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/event-classes/rpc-completed-event-class?view=sql-server-ver15). Am I right?

Comment: @Ronaldo, be aware that the trace can become quite large for all successful queries on an active server and expensive to query the XML. If you only need a count, play around with the XE histogram target.